# Was North Korea sanctioned for providing arms and advisors to Libya?

Tags: international-law, north-korea

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_North_Korea

In this article, we see that North Korea was caught providing weapons and advisors to Libya during the civil war, but I am wondering if this action was ever sanctioned. I know North Korea was sanctioned for its missile and ICBM programs, but I am not aware of North Korea ever being sanctioned for providing assistance to Libya.